# Insert only non-duplicates into MySQL table without key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL, and want to periodically insert new data from one into the other. As an example:

```
create table src(n integer, m integer);
create table dst(n integer, m integer);

insert ignore into dst(n, m) select n, m from src;
```

However, there is no key on dst, so this does not work! Furthermore, I can't create any key because we sometimes want to allow another process to create duplicates.

Here's how I've accomplished it right now; this seems like a hack-ish workaround, and I'm worried it won't be performant:

```
insert into dst(n, m)
select src.n, src.m
from src left outer join dst
on src.n = dst.n and src.m = dst.m
where dst.n is null and dst.m is null;
```

I've created indexes on dst to help with this, but a left outer join still seems too heavyweight. Is there a more canonical way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have indexes on (n, m) the performance should be acceptable.
Other that the way you're doing it, you could also do:

```
insert into dst(n, m)
select distinct src.n, src.m
from src 
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from dst D2 where src.n = D2.n and src.m = D2.m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a multi-column index: alter table YOURTABLE add unique index(n, m);
[Mysql manual reference to multi-column indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

You then want to do an INSERT IGNORE which will ignore any inserts where the existing index column exists.  You may want to do a INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE if you want the new duplicate to update the record, but from your comment, it looks like you just want the insert ignore.